# I need a way to combine high priority process with low CPU percentage for a background server

Tags: python, macos, unix, server, cpu-usage

I have a pipe coming from my Web server to my primary development desktop in order to have a slot open for heavy CPU processes without paying for the premium from Amazon or another cloud platform. I do however still use this machine for other personal things such as video encoding or gaming.

Is there a way to combine both a NICE value and a cpulimit value in order to slow down the maximum percentage of the CPU being used but it has the highest priority so it will absolutely be done when requested. Say for example I wanted 25% of my CPU available on demand to the process no matter what I was doing on the machine currently.

Ideally I would like it to be able to allow a higher percentage during times that I am not using the machine but setting a minimum that is always available.

Is there a clean way to do this? The only way that I found so far is by sticking the process in a separate virtual machine but it feels like I'm making things a whole lot more complicated than they need to be in order to make it run smoothly. On top of that, the ability to allow a higher percentage from a limited virtual machine currently doesn't exist as far as I know.

As a side note, I'm doing all this on a Mac so this solution will have to be Unix based. And the server I'm using is python's CherryPy for easy expansions on new developments.

Thank you in advance.